# Custom Closure Function Undefined JS Browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, iif

I have a very simple html page where I put this script at the end:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script(['studiomain.js']); ?>
</html>
```

The script contains an IIF in JS:

```
window.studiomain =  window.studiomain || (function ($) {
     let _dataTable = '';
     let _modalTemplates = {};
     let _webroot   = 'studioasq';
     function setDataTable (t, options={}) {
        _dataTable = $(t);
        if (typeof $(t).DataTable == 'function') {
           options.language = {
              "url": "/" + _webroot + "/js/datatable/i18n/Italian.json"
        }
        $(t).DataTable(options);
       }
    }
    function setModal(key='',template='') {
        _modalTemplates[key] = template;
    }
    function renderModal(key,data={}) {
       if (_modalTemplates[key] !== undefined) {
           let copy = _modalTemplates[key];
             Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {                
               copy.replace(new RegExp("{{" + value + "}}","g"),data[key]);
        })
       }
       return $('#'+key);        
    }
  return {
    setDataTable,
    setModal,
    renderModal
}

})($);
```

But when the page finishes loading, I have no studiomain in window:

```
window.studiomain => undefined.
```

I think the problem is the renderModal function: If I delete it all is fine.
What am I missing?

**** UPDATE ****

Following suggestions, I think the problem is in the order of loading scripts and passing the reference to JQuery.

I discovered also that passing (jQuery) and NOT ($) to the IIF works.

Comment: I'm not sure about the `php` part. but for `js` part, can you check if your function returns something?

Comment: hi, the script is correctly loaded and it return 3 functions

Comment: have you try `window.studiomain` code call after studiomain.js .And  call this function after window.load

Comment: "What am I missing?"  - A [mcve]

Comment: I tryied to call it in the console of chrome

Comment: can you confirm the console does not contain any error. (i.e. the function finish it's execution correctly)

Comment: https://jsbin.com/zapirabewa/1/edit?html,console — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is it possible you are calling the function from a file that is added before the part with the function.  So that it's called before it's been defined.  I think, as others cannot produce the error, that this may be a likely cause. But it's just a guess.  No way to know without more context.

Comment: Re edit: I still can't reproduce the problem: https://jsbin.com/tiseqimila/1/edit?html,console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to achieve modular pattern.

In your code, you'll need to return every thing inside a function, otherwise every code without return will be in private state.

Fix of your code, you need to return `window.studiomain` as a parameter, you code will work, `$` is not defined therefore it's not storing inside window object

```js
window.studiomain = window.studiomain || (function($) {
  let _dataTable = '';
  let _modalTemplates = {};
  let _webroot = 'studioasq';

  function setDataTable(t, options = {}) {
    _dataTable = $(t);
    if (typeof $(t).DataTable == 'function') {
      options.language = {
        "url": "/" + _webroot + "/js/datatable/i18n/Italian.json"
      }
      $(t).DataTable(options);
    }
  }

  function setModal(key = '', template = '') {
    _modalTemplates[key] = template;
  }

  function renderModal(key, data = {}) {
    if (_modalTemplates[key] !== undefined) {
      let copy = _modalTemplates[key];
      Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
        copy.replace(new RegExp("{{" + value + "}}", "g"), data[key]);
      })
    }
    return $('#' + key);
  }
  return {
    setDataTable,
    setModal,
    renderModal
  }

})(window.studiomain);

console.log(studiomain);
```

Comment: I think the problem is the renderModal function: If I delete it all is fine.

Comment: Try to return method with namespace, and the debug method if you this it's causing error.

Comment: thank you, it works.however how to pass $ (jquery?)

Comment: giuseppe, you can use another parameter